Iterate over divs to get tables using Selenium and Python
I'm trying to get info from the following site, using python and selenium:
https://conveniomarco.mercadopublico.cl/alimentos/marketplace/seller/profile/shop/797095-5800279
It has two sections:
"Condiciones Comerciales" and
"Condiciones Regionales"
I need to put all the tables of the section "Condiciones Regionales" in a dataframe, including the title that is outside of the table.
I can the all the tables info using the following code:
html=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body").get_attribute('outerHTML')
pd.read_html(html)[0]...
pd.read_html(html)[2]

But with this way, I lose the title, like "Region de Coquimbo", because this is not part of the table.
I've been trying to iterate over all the divs to get the title and then the inner table, with the following code:
condiciones_regionales=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wk_mp_design div.wk-mp-custom-regional div.wk-mp-profile-block div.wk-mp-aboutus-data div.box-regional-info")
condiciones=condiciones_regionales.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item")
    item2=[]
    for item2 in condiciones_regionales:
        print(item2.text)

but I get an error: "'WebElement' object is not iterable"
How can I solve it?
Thanks

You can get all those tables with the code below:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = 'https://conveniomarco.mercadopublico.cl/alimentos/marketplace/seller/profile/shop/797095-5800279'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

cod_reg_div = soup.select_one('div[id="box-content-regional"]')
titles = cod_reg_div.select('div[class="item"] div[class="title"]')
for t in titles:
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(t.find_next('div', {'class': 'content'}))))[0]
    df['region'] = t.text.strip()
    print(df)

Result in terminal:
    0   1   region
0   Nombre del Contacto EGIDIO VILLA    Región de Antofagasta
1   Teléfono de Contacto    29335564    Región de Antofagasta
2   Correo de Contacto  egidio.villa@sidapt.cl  Región de Antofagasta
3   Plazo de entrega máximo (días hábiles)  10  Región de Antofagasta
4   Tiempo de entrega en emergencia o catástrofe (...   192 Región de Antofagasta
5   Monto Máximo Orden de Compra    $0  Región de Antofagasta
6   Comunas de la región donde no se realiza despacho   NaN Región de Antofagasta
0   1   region
0   Nombre del Contacto EGIDIO VILLA    Región de Coquimbo
1   Teléfono de Contacto    29335564    Región de Coquimbo
2   Correo de Contacto  egidio.villa@sidapt.cl  Región de Coquimbo
3   Plazo de entrega máximo (días hábiles)  5   Región de Coquimbo
4   Tiempo de entrega en emergencia o catástrofe (...   72  Región de Coquimbo
5   Monto Máximo Orden de Compra    $0  Región de Coquimbo
6   Comunas de la región donde no se realiza despacho   NaN Región de Coquimbo

[...]

For pandas docs, go here, and for requests, here.

Thanks. Is it a bad idea to use selenium for this? I've done all the code in selenium, except this :)(
